# What number tetrated by itself equals a googol?

Tags: tetration

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Tetrating stuff makes it really big really fast.  I'm trying to figure out what number would equal a googol.  Any help?

Or a googolplex ?

Comment: Well, $3^{3^3}$ has $12$ digits and is much smaller than googol, where $4^{4^{4^4}}$ has $8.072\cdot 10^{153}$ digits, and is thus much bigger than googol*plex*.

Comment: @Meelo: I think that should be an answer; since real-valued tetration isn't particularly well-defined, it's hard to see how to do much better than that...

Comment: $$b_1 \approx 3.22192863\; ; \;\;\; b_2 \approx 3.96367752$$
$$b_1 \uparrow \uparrow b_1 \approx 10^{100}$$
$$b_2 \uparrow \uparrow b_2 \approx 10^{10^{100}}$$

Analytic extension of tetration results using http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use essentially guess and check.

Consider $X = 3$

Then:

$$Tetration(3,3) = 3^{(3^3)} = 3^{(27)}$$

Too small, lets try bigger

$$Tetration(4,4) = 4^{(4^{4^4})} = 4^{4^{256}}  \text{~ ~} 4^{10^{155}} $$

That's getting better. Interpolating any further is tricky business and may require some specialized tools.

The users here: http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/index.php

Would probably be well equipped to answer your question

Comment: Your tower of 4s is not tall enough -- you're computing ${}^34$, not ${}^44$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks! you're right I made a mistake